# Cumulants of Meixner distribution

Tags: options, option-pricing

Hey characteristic function of Meixner distribution is:
$$\Phi(u)=\left(\frac{\cos(\beta/2)}{\cosh((\alpha u-i\beta)/2}\right)^{2\delta}$$
I need to calculate the first, second, and fourth cumulant of this distribution i.e $c_n=\frac{1}{i^n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial u^n}\ln(\Phi(u))$ at $u=0$. Does anyone have the appropriate software and could give me these values?

Comment: Would this help: Page 4 of https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00514334/document ?

Comment: Thanks :) Is there a big difference when we use a distribution with additional parameter $m$? Because in Schoutens (2003) book he use a mexiner distribution without $m$ parameter and I dont know if we get much better result when we add $m$.